# How is the output of this Python expression generated?

Tags: python, lambda

Could someone explain what the output of this expression is and how it is generated. I know I can put this in IDLE and check the output but I want to learn how to do it manually. Specifically, I would like to know how the print statement is executed step by step.

```
def f(x):
    return lambda y: (x, y(x))
def g(y):
    return lambda x: x(y)
print(g(2)(f)(lambda x:x+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is all purely functional code (except for `print` itself), so we can just use substitution to visualize what's going on:

```
print(g(2)(f)(lambda x:x+1))
#     ^^^^
```

Step 1: Call `g` with `2`, binding `g`'s argument `y` to `2` ...

```
def g(y):  # y = 2
    return lambda x: x(y)
```

... giving `lambda x: x(2)`.

```
print((lambda x: x(2))(f)(lambda x:x+1))
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Step 2: Call the `lambda` function (that was returned from `g`) with `f` ...

```
(lambda x: x(2))  # x = f
#          ^^^^
```

... which in turn calls `f` with `2` ...

```
def f(x):  # x = 2
    return lambda y: (x, y(x))
```

... giving `lambda y: (2, y(2))`:

```
print((lambda y: (2, y(2)))(lambda x:x+1))
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Step 3: Call the `lambda` function (that was returned from `f` via the other `lambda`) with `lambda x:x+1` ...

```
(lambda y: (2, y(2))  # y = lambda x:x+1
#              ^^^^
```

... giving `(2, (lambda x:x+1)(2))`, which in turn calls the argument `lambda` function with `2` ...

```
lambda x:x+1  # x = 2
```

... giving `3`, which is then incorporated into the result of the outer `lambda`, giving `(2, 3)`:

```
print((2, 3))
#^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is finally the point at which `print` is invoked, passing a tuple as argument.